# Force a click on right side of Win10 touchpad to register as right-click

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I have a RAZER BLADE Stealth 13 laptop, running Windows 10 Home Edition. I want to know if there is a way where I can click anywhere on the right-hand side of the touchpad, and have the computer interpret it as a right-click. There exists an option in Windows 10 to set the bottom-right corner of the touchpad to right-click, but I personally felt that the region was too small for my liking.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If the option exists, it exists with an application provided by your laptop manufacturer. With the Razer Blade 13, it looks like the touchpad is made by Synaptics. If their utility doesn't provide the ability to change the touch zone size, you might be out of luck. There are no options in Windows to set the size of the right click area on the touchpad.

You could use two finger tap for right click, and then you can tap anywhere. Not a solution to your specific problem, but a workaround nonetheless.

Not sure what these "hidden settings" are, but here's a post about unlocking some additional settings on a Synaptics touch pad.

https://7thzero.com/blog/unlock-hidden-synaptics-touch-pad-settings-windows-10